# Convert Powershell to Nested Json

Tags: json, powershell

So I have been trying to solve this problem for a couple of days and just can't seem to find anything that works, so I am hoping you may be able to help or point me in the right direction.

I am creating a powershell script that creates service accounts in Active Directory, at the very end of the script the username and password and then stored in an Enterprise Password Vault. A REST Api is used to store the credentials within this Vault. I am having a slight issue converting my powershell into nested Json, without the nested it works fine...

The JSON output I need to get to is this:

```
{
"account":{
    "safe":"Test_safe",
    "platformID":"WindowsDomainAccount",
    "address":"ad.local",
    "password":"password",
    "username":"test",
    "disableAutoMgmt":"true",
    "disableAutoMgmtReason":"test",
    "properties":
    [
    {"Key":"Title", "Value":"Test Account"},
    {"Key":"Description", "Value":"REQ0000001"},
    ]
  }
}
```

and this is my Powershell excluding nesting of "properties" which works fine.

```
   $hash = [ordered]@{
        account = [ordered]@{
            safe="ServiceAccounts"; 
            platformID="WindowsDomainAccount";
            address="ad.local";
            password="Password1";
            username="svc-test";
            disableAutoMgmt="true";
            disableAutoMgmtReason="testing";
        }
   }

$json = $hash | ConvertTo-Json

$invoke = Invoke-Webrequest -Uri $url -Method "POST" -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Header @{"Authorization" = $header} -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable WebError
```

The problems start when I try to add to my powershell

```
"properties":
    [
    {"Key":"Title", "Value":"Test Account"},
    {"Key":"Description", "Value":"REQ0000001"},
    ]
```

I think my first problem is that the word Key is also a powershell keyword.

I have tried a lot of different combinations and tried lots of things from other articles I have found, but the majority of things I am finding are to do with parsing a nested Jason back via Powershell.

Hope that all makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code below works for me (PS v4) and seems to return json in the format you want.

```
$hash = [ordered]@{
    account = [ordered]@{
        safe="ServiceAccounts"; 
        platformID="WindowsDomainAccount";
        address="ad.local";
        password="Password1";
        username="svc-test";
        disableAutoMgmt="true";
        disableAutoMgmtReason="testing";

        properties = @(
            @{"Key"="Title"; "Value"="Test Account"},
            @{"Key"="Description"; "Value"="REQ0000001"}
        )

    }
}

$json = $hash | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
$json
```

the output of the above...

```js
{
    "account":  {
                    "safe":  "ServiceAccounts",
                    "platformID":  "WindowsDomainAccount",
                    "address":  "ad.local",
                    "password":  "Password1",
                    "username":  "svc-test",
                    "disableAutoMgmt":  "true",
                    "disableAutoMgmtReason":  "testing",
                    "properties":  [
                                       {
                                           "Key":  "Title",
                                           "Value":  "Test Account"
                                       },
                                       {
                                           "Key":  "Description",
                                           "Value":  "REQ0000001"
                                       }
                                   ]
                }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I think i was getting confused with what type of brackets to use. Simple silly mistake, but thank you :)

Comment: `-Depth 99` is what I was looking for :)